# std::upper_bound returns const iterator in const member function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, circular-buffer

Here is a class that contains a `boost::circular_buffer` of some `struct`. I make a typedef for iterators into the contained `circular_buffer`.

My problem is this: when the `doWork` function is marked `const`, the returned value of `std::upper_bound` is not compatible with the `MyIterator` type due to the return value having `boost::cb_details::const_traits`. If I remove the `const` keyword from the function, all my compile errors go away.

To be clear the compiler error is this:

> ```
> error: conversion from ‘boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<Wrapper<int>::Sample, std::allocator<Wrapper<int>::Sample> >, boost::cb_details::const_traits<std::allocator<Wrapper<int>::Sample> > >’ to non-scalar type ‘Wrapper<int>::MyIterator {aka boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<Wrapper<int>::Sample, std::allocator<Wrapper<int>::Sample> >, boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits<std::allocator<Wrapper<int>::Sample> > >}’ requested    
>                           [](const Sample& a, const Sample& b) { return a.foo < b.foo; });
> ```

Here is a self-contained example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
 public:
    struct Sample {
        T foo;
    };

    typedef typename boost::circular_buffer<Sample>::iterator MyIterator;

    Wrapper(int size) { cb.resize(size); }

    void add(T val) { cb.push_back(Sample{val}); }

    void doWork(T bound) const {
        MyIterator iter =
            std::upper_bound(cb.begin(), cb.end(), Sample{3},
                         [](const Sample& a, const Sample& b) { return a.foo < b.foo; });
    }

    boost::circular_buffer<Sample> cb;
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<int> buf(100);
    buf.add(1);
    buf.add(5);
    buf.doWork(3);
    return 0;
}
```

So, why can't this function be const? Why does marking it const have this side-effect? I want a non-const iterator into the container, but in my real test case I don't intend to actually modify the container at all.

Comment: Well since `doWork` is `const`, `cb` is treated as `const` as well. Since `doWork` does not intend on modifying `cb` use `const_iterator` instead.

Comment: An MCVE! Wonders never cease. +1

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Answer section is down below, friend

Comment: Why not just use `auto iter = std::upper_bound(...`?

Comment: @Galik amen to `auto`, especially since this is tagged c++11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going to need a `const_iterator`, since you're effectively observing a `const` container.

Perhaps:

```
typedef typename boost::circular_buffer<Sample>::const_iterator MyConstIterator;
```

… then make `iter` one of these.

Someone's going to tell you that you could have avoided this with `auto`. That's true, but then you never would have discovered this "bug", or that `const_iterator`s exist.

Answer (score 4):

If your function is marked `const` then all your access to member variables will be `const` too.

A `const` container will only allow access to `const_` iterators, that's just the way iterators work.